# Get Refunds List in Shopify with Date Filter (Not Orders)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

```
`GET /admin/api/2022-10/orders.json?financial_status=refunded,partially_refunded&fields=refunds&created_at_min=2022-10-05T00:00:00-05:00&created_at_max=2022-11-17T24:00:00-05:00&limit=250&since_id=0&status=any`
```

We are using this API to fetch the refunds list. Actually we want to fetch refunds on Date base like refunds with in
specific date but Shopify does not provide any refund Listing API to get the refunds on date basis.

So if a refund is issued after
two months (Order in Dec-> Refund in Feb) then we have it in the order list of that month (Dec)but not in the order list of after two months (Feb).

Answer (score 1):

Refunds in Shopify are just a property within orders.
The [`order resource`](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/order#resource-object) schema looks like this :

```
{
    "created_at": "date the order was placed",
    "processed_at": "date the order was imported",
    "refunds": [
        {
            "created_at": "date the refund was created",
            "processed_at": "date the refund was processed"
        }
    ]
}
```

To filter refunds by date, you'll need to fetch the orders list then use the refund's `created_at` or `processed_at` properties to filter them in the order you want : either when the refund request was issued or when it was processed.

Comment: I have tried using this but lets say we fetch order of January and filter with created_at -> We will get those refunds which were created in January. But if there are some refunds which are created_ at Feb? how to fetch them in Feb like in Feb order we will not be getting January orders, Hope so you will be getting my point.

Comment: I don't see any other way than looping through all orders on your store. Because if a refund is created in Feb for an order from 6 months ago, that information (the refund's created_at property) is stored inside of the order from 6 months ago. So you can't know in advance how far you should go in your order history to get every refunds created in Feb.

Answer (score 0):

There is not current API which provides direct refund access like orders. You can fetch it through the order list or order ids.